# Keep Silverlight application always in fullscreen mode

Tags: silverlight, fullscreen

I'm going to make a full screen Silverlight (version 5, VS 2012) application so that user can never take it out of full-screen mode, also users should not be able to use shortcut keys like F11, F5, Ctrl-S and so on. In fact I need an isolated environment in which nothing other that my application works. What are my options? Out-of-browser (if so, how can I remove title bar), Silverlight in browser (if so how can I disable browser shortcut keys?

Comment: +1 ....but it would have to be a "trusted" application, and you'll have to write in a handler to ignore function keys etc but getting it to also ignore things like alt+tab, windowsbutton+tab etc will be even more difficult. If you haven't already, I would start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(v=vs.95).aspx) and there will be lots more reading required after that.

Comment: thanks, what you mean by trusted application? should I user Out-Of-Browser or in-browser?

Comment: It's the way of requiring elevated trust to reach outside the sandbox. You'll see it mentioned on the link provided, which will also likely inevitably lead you to yet even more reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx). :)